# using if statement with bigger than and less than

Tags: android, if-statement

so what i have is 2 editText one for minimum number and one for maximum number and when the user clicks the button the app generate a random number between the 2 given number (I got it) but if the user entered the maximum number in the minimum number field the app crashes what i want to accomplish is if the user enters the maximum number in the minimum number field set the maximum number field to minimum number + 1 and try again automatically  I tried the code below and its working if the user entered the values in the right please but if the user entered the maximum number in the minimum number field the app crash

```
    Button gen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    final EditText mini = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mini);
    final EditText maxi = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.maxi);
    final TextView res = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

    final Random r = new Random();
    final int[] number = {0};

   gen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

           int minn = Integer.parseInt(mini.getText().toString());
           int maxx = Integer.parseInt(maxi.getText().toString());

           if (minn>=maxx){
               maxi.setText(minn+1);
               maxx = Integer.parseInt(maxi.getText().toString());
               number[0] = minn + r.nextInt(maxx - minn + 1);
               res.setText(String.valueOf(number[0]));
           }else{
               number[0] = minn + r.nextInt(maxx - minn + 1);

               res.setText(String.valueOf(number[0]));
           } 

       }
   });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following...

```
maxi.setText(minn+1);
```

With...

```
maxi.setText(String.valueOf(minn+1));
```

Passing **int** value instead of **String** value into the **setText** method causing the crash problem.

Comment: yup but it will be a compile time error and not a CRASH as the user said

Comment: @SrinathGanesh...I checked it myself just now...setting **int** instead of **String** is the culprit.

Comment: yup i know its a fault ,but that will give a COMPILE TIME ERROR

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do something like this:

```
if (minn>=maxx){
           maxi.setText(String.valueOf(minn));
           mini.setText(String.valueOf(maxx));
           maxx = Integer.parseInt(maxi.getText().toString());
           minn = Integer.parseInt(minn.getText().toString());
           number[0] = minn + r.nextInt(maxx - minn + 1);
           res.setText(String.valueOf(number[0]));
       }
number[0] = minn + r.nextInt(maxx - minn + 1);    
res.setText(String.valueOf(number[0]));
```

Comment: How can you pass an **int** value into the **setText** method when its required **String** value?